# Append Text in Last Column Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to append the text in last column of the table (grid like structure). Like below

[image]

When Click on `Add` button i want to append some text in last column adjacent to `Add` button. I am getting repated text on click of `Add` as in picture above.

This is what i have tried so far (one step away):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.new').on('click', function(){  
    var recId= $(this).parents("#myTable td:last-child");
     recId.append('<b>Sometext</b>');
     recId.css("background-color", "lightgreen");
   });
});
```

Can someone help me rectify this, [Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgupta17/9c7g9/)

**Edit for Clarity in question**

`Sometext` added in last column is dynamic and click event on `Add` button should fire multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.new').on('click', function(){  
        var recId= $(this).parents("#myTable td:last-child");
        recId.find('b').remove(); //remove text
        recId.append('<b>Sometext</b>');
        recId.css("background-color", "lightgreen");
    });
});
```

[`DEMO here.`](http://jsfiddle.net/9c7g9/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element per event type.

```
$('.new').one('click', function () {
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GLpBW/)</kbd>

---

Updated after OP's comment.

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GLpBW/1)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.new').on('click', function () {
        var recId = $(this).parents("#myTable td:last-child");
        if (recId.text().indexOf("Sometext") === -1) { //if it contains Sometext it will not append it again but if it's a new value it will append it
            recId.append('<b>Sometext</b>');
            recId.css("background-color", "lightgreen");
        }
    });
});
```

---

Better code

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GLpBW/2)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.new').on('click', function () {
        var recId = $(this).parent();
        recId.find('b').remove();
        recId.append('<b>Sometext</b>');
        recId.css("background-color", "lightgreen");
    });
});
```

Comment: Solution is valid to problem presented, but the `sometext` i have added is dynamic coming from async ajax call. Hence i want event to fire more than one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my `sometext` is dynamic hence this solution may not work. I have checked for Hiral solution it works the same way i want.

Comment: Yes, `SomeText` is different always i have used for reference purpose only.

Comment: @Pratik checl out --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/GLpBW/2 works as you want and is fast .

Answer (score 1):

i did this to your JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.new').on('click', function(){  
        var recId= $(this).parents("#myTable td:last-child");
        if (!recId.hasClass("changed")) {
            recId.append('<b>Sometext</b>');
            recId.css("background-color", "lightgreen");
            recId.addClass("changed");
        }
    });
});
```

checking if the td has the class "changed", if not: add text, change bgcolor and the add the class "changed" so the event can fire but won't do anything to the same td twice.

Comment: I belive this will work for first event raised. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Misinterpreted your question a little. No problem (=